# Is it possible to disable fsevents warning without changing npm loglevel config?

Tags: node.js, npm

Since the day I use nodejs and npm, every time I do installing some package, npm always give me a warning:

```
fsevents@1.0.17: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
```

I know I can set npm `loglevel` to `error`, I did that before and then something
went wrong because I miss some warning from another package.

Is there any npm or yarn configuration that can white list a warning for some specific package?